# Different result using welch function between Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab

When I run welch function on the same data in Matlab and Python, I get slightly PSD estimation difference, while the sample frequencies are identical.

Here is the parameters i used in both Matlab and Python:
Matlab:

```
winlength=512;
overlap=0;
fftlength=1024;
fs=127.886;
[PSD, freqs] = pwelch(data, winlength, overlap, fftlength, fs);
```

Python:

```
freqs, PSD = welch(data, fs=127.886, window='hamming', nperseg=512,
noverlap=None, nfft=1024)
```

here's a plot presenting the difference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ND0w.png)

Does anyone have any idea what should I change to get the same results of PSD?

Answer (score 1):

In the Matlab documentation https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html it says that the overlap parameter has to be a positive integer thus 0 is not a valid value.

If you omit the overlap value - (or declare a non-valid value) the parameter is **automatically** set to a 50% overlap i.e. changing the curve.

Try to set the Python function to a 50% overlap and see if they match.

BTW you rarely want to have zero overlap as this is likely to cause transients in the signal.

Comment: What I did is to set noverlap=o (in Python of course) and it looks much better. Thanks!

Comment: That's good. Out out curiosity why is there a difference between "none" and "0". Does the Python method have a similar documentation only accepting positive integers and thereby applying a 50% overlap when you write "none"?
Remember to upvote if the answer helped you :)